# Videojs play button displaying while video is playing in Safari only

Tags: javascript, video, safari, html5-video

i have got a seriously annoying bug that is causing me issues on [this page](http://www.topshop.com/en/tsuk/category/look-of-the-day-monikh-february-2014-2692703/home?TS=1392299039147&intcmpid=W_HERO_WELOVE_UK_WK25_PS_LOOK_FEATURE_MONIKHLFW), but only on Safari 6.1 on a Mac. I am using the videojs library to do video detection and fallback into Flash on older browsers. The videojs library adds a play button to the DOM for each video when it initialises, that you can click to start the video playing. It also helpfully adds **vjs-paused** and **vjs-playing** to the video container depending on its state, and i am using these to hide the play button when the video is playing.

On all other browsers than Safari 6.1 this works fine, but in this browser the first video plays ok but any subsequent videos on the page still show the play button over the top of video when started which is very ugly. The most annoying this is that if i open up the dev tools and un-tick the display: none styling then re-tick it, it suddenly works fine. It is like giving the browser a poke and it suddenly realizing "hey, i'm not supposed to be showing this i'd better hide it quick".

If anyone can offer me any pointers on what is causing this i'd really appreciate it as i am going crazy trying to figure it out.

Thanks

edit: 
Finally figured this one out, thought i'd leave the answer here in  case anyone was experiencing the same issues as me. It occurs when multiple instances of the videojs script are loaded onto the page. They end up conflicting with each other. Hope this helps anyone with the same issues i had. Thanks for your responses guys.

Comment: I have been doing a bit more investigation and if i take all my videojs event handlers out like the pause/play/end then the error still occurs, and it only ever occurs where there are more than 1 video on the page. [Here is a simplified version of the page](http://www.topshop.com/test/video-template/videojs-control.html) to test on.

Comment: Sorry mate I cecked it with Safari 7.0.2 and it was there as well. So it more wide spead than you though, it's on the newest safari as well. It must be the way they add in the *display: none*, because in my Safari I can't even trigger it with the inspector and althogh the styles do show it, the computed values completey ignore it. I would look into it more, but all of your code is minified. Unfortunatelly the best advice I can give you at this point is to simply report this as an error to the videojs libary developers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a mac here but have you tried applying [backface-visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_backface-visibility.asp) css property to the play button?

[Here is a similar link](http://www.sitepoint.com/fix-chrome-animation-flash-bug/), resetting css3 hardware-acceleration/gpu related properties have often fixed strange display bugs for me. Good luck!